# How to keep new line spacing consistant

Tags: python

As shown by the print out, each line should consist of a a name that has had its characters reversed followed by a birthdate that has had its format converted to a European format.

The last line however prints out two of these lines next to each other without a space. I was wondering how to avoid this and have both names/birthdates print on separate lines as those above them.

```
def mirror(text): 
    back = ""
    for i in range(1, len(text)):
        back = back + text[len(text) - i]
    return back 
while True: 
    try: 
        file = input('Please enter the name of the file you would like to open: ') 
        text = open(file) 
        break 
    except: 
        print('Please enter a valid file.')
        continue 
lines = text.readlines()
for line in lines: 
    part = line[0:8].split('/') 
    dd = part[0]
    mm = part[1] 
    yy = part[2] 
    text = line[8:] 
    name = mirror(text)
    print(name + " " + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy, end = "")
```

The actual results are:

```
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00senoJ moT 02/01/00
```

while the ones I would like are:

```
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
senoJ moT 02/01/00
```

Comment: A bare `except` is never a very good idea.

Comment: Your new line is at the end of each line in the `lines` list. Reversing the `text` makes the new lines be the first thing to be printed. So the missing new line is because your file doesnt end with a new line character.

Answer (score 1):

The default for the `end` attribute of the print function is to add a new line character to the end of the string. With `end = ""` you have told it you don't want anything on the end. Remove that and it should provide the desired output.

Also, if you're not using the `with open as` convention for dealing with files, you're going to have to `text.close()` when you're done with it.